# how to place a custom footer on a single page

Tags: header-footer, luatex, fancyhdr

I've written a class that tries to get rid off the header/footer by default and it sets the margins the way I like:

```
\pagestyle{plain}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1cm}
```

it works, but I would like to place a custom footer (custom text) on the last page. I took a look to `fancyhdr` and some suggestion around here, but I've noot been able to do it the right way. I placed `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` in my `.tex` preamble, and the following code before the ending tag of the document:

```
  \fancypagestyle{autorizzazione} {
  \fancyfoot[C]{Autorizzo il trattamento dei dati personali ai sensi del D. lgs. 196/03}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
  \pagestyle{autorizzazione}
```

but that didn't draw any footer at all, although I didn't get any error from compilation

Comment: It can be done. Code too complex and user-specific for here. General idea: Don't use fancyhdr for that. Instead, use pagestyle empty, and manually place the custom footer using `textpos` package to position the desired text where a footer would ordinarily be.

Comment: can you confirm I'm not seeing the footer because of the `plain` pagestyle? I've tried other page style but nothing happens

Comment: @RobtAll works like charm. Thanks for your piece of advice

Comment: tikzpagnodes is another possibility: \node[anchor=base] at (current page footer area.south) {...};

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the definition code in the document body. Define the pagestyle in the preamble and use it then in the page:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{autorizzazione} {%
   \fancyfoot[C]{Autorizzo il trattamento dei dati personali ai sensi del D. lgs. 196/03}}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
blb
\newpage 
blb
\newpage \thispagestyle{autorizzazione}
blblb
\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: My example works fine for me. There is footline on page 3. If it doesn't work for you, show the log-file.

Comment: Sure, here you go https://gist.github.com/bertuz/10f8ae885d2004c495f843d3e9759160

Comment: This is not the log-file of my example. E.g. I don't load fontspec.

Comment: nobody lives in a sandbox, so I've tried it into my real world scenario. In other words I've set the `\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1cm}` I needed. That way, your example does not work anymore. It compiles, but the footer is way too low to be visible. I solved by using the solution RobtAll mentioned above, but still it would be nice understanding the behavior

Comment: You can adapt my example later.The first step is always to try out the example as it is. When you then change it, and something breaks  you can show this change and then ask why this change is a problem. Simply saying "nothing happens" without mentioning that you tried out something quite different is wasting my time. Using texpos for this type of problems is imho nonsense. How will you align the text with your page number on the other pages?

Comment: I don't want any page number, that's why I set `\pagestyle{plain}`. I would assume the starting point as the one I described in the question, but it looks it places the footer way too low, and that's why it compiles correctly but does not appear

Comment: Plain contains a number, empty is empty. Your question is incomplete it contains only code snippets that can not be tested but a margin of one cm sounds a bit small.

Comment: Correct, I've tried to set a bigger margin and the fancyheader makes its jobs by placing it correctly. Since I prefer to keep those very thin margins, I keep the `textpos` solution, but at least everything is explained and `fancyhdr` is a viable neat solution

Comment: Make footskip smaller: `\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1cm,footskip=5mm}`.

Answer (score 1):

As [RobtAll](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/139954/robtall) mentioned, a workable way is using [`Textpos`](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/textpos/textpos.pdf):

```
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\textblockorigin{1cm}{\paperheight-1cm}

\begin{document}
  ...

  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth-1cm}(0mm,0mm)
      Hi! I'm a fake footer
  \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right. I do it all the time, but my method is deeply entwined with other code I use (too complicated for here). I think there's a way you can mark your reply as answering your own question. Note that the textpos method allows you to place a "footer" in the lower margin, even if the document layout normally has no footer. There's also a way to shorten the number of lines on a per-page basis, so that a fake footer can be positioned where the last line would normally be.